# Why there are too many symbols in .dynsym table

Tags: android

I created one game .so file by Android NDK and found there are too many symbols in .dynsym table.

For example, I am using icu (international components for unicode) libraries, and I  found there are many icu symbols in .dynsym sections. But certainly I linked only the static libraries.

Does anyone know any clue for this? How I can remove those symbols and save the memory?

Thanks a lot!
Young

Comment: Have you tried adding `-Wl,--exclude-libs,ALL` to your linker flags when building the shared library?

Comment: Yes, it works! Thanks a lot. Now I found that many global variable in my code are put into .dynsym table automatically. I used "-fvisibility=hidden", but it did not work. Do you know whether there is anyway to remove those variables from .dynsym table? Thanks